# cancatenate two strings in a dict

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

views.py

```
 def method(request):

        for member in list:
            personname = {'id':member.id,
                         'name':member.firstname  +  member.lastname
                       } 
        return render(request,'some.html',{'name':personname})
```

In the above views.py,i used concatenation operator to concatenate firstname and lastname.Concatenation is  happening,i need to make a space between firstname and lastname.I simply used " " but giving syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `+` for concatenating firstname, space and lastname strings:

```
personname = {'id':member.id,
              'name': member.firstname  + " " + member.lastname}
```

Or use string formatting:

```
personname = {'id':member.id,
              'name': '%s %s' % (member.firstname, member.lastname)}
```

Or `format`:

```
personname = {'id':member.id,
              'name': '{0} {1}'.format(member.firstname, member.lastname)}
```